# binding single sf:input spring form tag with multiple bean attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

i want to make a form using spring tags such that user can login with his email or mobile number or user name and password.

```
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginBean">
    <label for="user_email">User Name/Email/Mobile:</label>
    <sf:input path="email,mobile,username" value="${user.email}" />

    <label for="user_password">Password:</label>
    <sf:input path="password" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</sf:form>
```

LoginBean

```
public class LoginBean {
private String email;
private String password;
private String mobile;
private String username;
//getter setter 
}
```

I am stuck here to bind a single input tag with multiple bean attribute.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be 2 approached:

1. Use single `String login` field in the LoginBean and one form field with `login` path. On the server side you should somehow recognize what is entered and do 3 attempts to login depending on the recognized way.

-

```
tryLoginWithEmail(loginBeanInstance.getLogin(), loginBeanInstance.getPassoword()); 
tryLoginWithMobile(loginBeanInstance.getLogin(), loginBeanInstance.getPassoword());
tryLoginWithUsername(loginBeanInstance.getLogin(), loginBeanInstance.getPassoword());
```

2. Create a 3 form fields and add some logic to allow only one field to be filled. The login according to the not empty field.

UPDATE:

3. Create one method tryComplexLogin(login, password) where you can try to find user with the password and login checking  all the 3 field values in DB

like

```
select * from users
where
  (name =:loginNameParam and password=:passwordParam)
OR
  (email =:loginNameParam and password=:passwordParam)
OR
  (mobile =:loginNameParam and password=:passwordParam)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. first one is looking quite good. please tell me in second method i.e.  Create a 3 form fields then all will be visible to user or only one.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. It could be radiobuttons to choose which  field to be used. Or all the 3 fields and 2 becomes disabled when one is filled.